# Correct sequence and activity diagrams (UML)

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram

Im working through practice problems in my textbook and was hoping you guys could "grade" my answers for these two questions. I have attached a picture with the questions and diagrams and I'll retype the questions below:

1) Draw a sequence diagram for an application that a user uses to withdraw money. The application sends to a web service two things in this process. One, the users credit card information and two, requests money/new balance.

2)Draw an activity diagram of someone registering for a website. They must first request a username, and if that username is not rejected they must next submit an email. If that email is not rejected, then they get sent a confirmation email. After any rejection or a sent confirmation email, the application closes.

[image: Diagrams]

Answer (score 0):

It is really good for the first work!

Only some changes in notification:

`Quit` is shown as filled black circle of the size of a large letter. You should write *Quit* or *End* or something of the sort near it.

Initial node is the same point at start. With word *Start* or something of the sort near it. `Submit Name` is an action (ok to show it in a circle, tools show them as rounded blocks), and should go AFTER initial node.

You don't need to show the time direction - downward is the default time direction. You can to do it as a comment, of course, but you needn't.

As for content, it is simply correct. You can be proud - That is the first time I am seeing here a diagram for evaluation with correct content.

Please, the next time use some tool for diagrams - have pity for our eyes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Activity diagram is basically a flowchart to represent the flow from one activity to another activity. The activity of the system can be described as an operation of the system. It represents the sequence of activities.

The control flow is drawn from one operation to another. This flow can be sequential, branched, or concurrent. That is the point that it's get different from the flowchart. It includes These additional capabilities branching, parallel flow.
Before drawing your diagram you have to identify what are the activities, associations, conditions. In here
Activities that I identified are

- User will enter a Username and it should validate
- User will enter a Email and it should validate
- Email should confirm by the system

  I assumed that If the user inputs for an invalid name or an invalid email, system will display a message and considering the option of user, quit from the system.
  As well as for the email, if email the email is not confirmed, then user will able to choose either enter new email or proceed with current email by confirming it.

[image]

And also use starting and terminating initials when you drawing an activity diagram